Log analysis and send SNMP Trap
Log files will be generated in the multiple servers. All the logs generated needs to be monitored and then if any key found in the log like "Error occurred ABC" then immediately SNMP trap needs to be sent to a server.
I am looking for open source solution with minimum hardware requirement and memory foot print.
Will Logstash with SNMP plugin work? Also is other open source tool available.
